# two select boxes filtering options with jquery

Tags: jquery, select

I have two select boxes generated by php

```
    <div id="option-264" class="option">
        <span class="required">*</span>
        <b>Board Type:</b><br />
        <select name="option[264]" class="optionChoice">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="20">All Mountain </option>
            <option value="21">Straight Jibber </option>
            <option value="22">Bender </option>
            <option value="23">Tripod </option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="option-265" class="option">
        <span class="required">*</span>
        <b>Board Size:</b><br />
        <select name="option[265]" class="optionChoice">
            <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
            <option value="17">146                        </option>
            <option value="18">147                        </option>
            <option value="19">149                        </option>
            <option value="24">150                        </option>
            <option value="25">152                        </option>
            <option value="26">153                        </option>
            <option value="27">155                        </option>
            <option value="28">156                        </option>
            <option value="29">157                        </option>
            <option value="30">158                        </option>
            <option value="31">159                        </option>
         </select>
    </div>
```

i want to either hide or grey out options one the other select depending on the change of the current select box.

i.e. if i select board type "straight jibber" it only comes in "152" "155" and "159" so i want to hide everything else.

hope that makes sense

```
      function displayVals() {
       var Values = $("#option-264>select").val();
       var Sizes = $("#option-265>select");
       switch (Values) { 
    case '20': 
        $("#option-265").fadeOut();
        $("#option-265>select option[value='18']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='19']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='26']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='27']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='29']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='30']").attr("disabled","disabled");
         $("#option-265").fadeIn(); 
        break;
    case '21': 
        $("#option-265").fadeOut();
        $("#option-265>select option[value='18']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='24']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='26']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='28']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='30']").attr("disabled","disabled");
         $("#option-265").fadeIn(); 
        break;
    case '22': 
        $("#option-265").fadeOut();
        $("#option-265>select option[value='18']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='24']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='26']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='28']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='30']").attr("disabled","disabled");
         $("#option-265").fadeIn(); 
        break;
    case '23': 
        $("#option-265").fadeOut();
        $("#option-265>select option[value='18']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='24']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='26']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='28']").attr("disabled","disabled");
        $("#option-265>select option[value='30']").attr("disabled","disabled");
         $("#option-265").fadeIn();  
        break;
    case '': 
        $("#option-265").fadeOut();
        break;
}
}
$("#option-264>select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

i hacked away at it and sort of got it working (with the ugliest code iv seen) id prefer if i could hide the options not just grey them out though.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: No, that makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('select[name="option[264]"]').change(function(value) {
    var selected = $(this).children('option:selected').val();

    //hide all options
    $('select[name="option[265]"] option').hide(); 

    //show options based on initial selection
    if (selected == 20) {
        $('select[name="option[265]"]').find('option:contains("152"), option:contains("155"), option:contains("159")').show();
    } else if (selected == 21) {
       //etc etc
    }
});​
```

Definitely not the most elegant solution, I'll admit.

Comment: nice i think option:contains will really help me tidy it up thnks

Answer (score 0):

Actually i didn't get u properly but.. what i understood u have select box which is coming dyanamically u want its value to hide , show, etc after change..

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#id_name_ur').change(function() {

           if(jQuery('#Idname option:selected').val() != ''){

$(this).hide(); 
                    //like this u can got ur solutions ...
    // put ur code here
                   alert("you selected an option");
    return true;
                }else{
    alert("please select an option");
    return false;
    }


    });

        });
    </script>
```